# Does a variable in a main script transfer to a invoke-expression-script?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a script run each time a new file is created. I need the filename and path for the new file to work in my Invoke-Expression Action script. Does the variable $filePath transfer to the Action script? Or do I need to get the filename in the Action script? I have one wokring sollution that gets the latest file in the folder, but in worst case, that might be the wrong file if to files are created at almost the same time, so I would prefer to transfer the path\name of the file that triggered the file wathcer script. I cant find a way to whatch what the program does (a log), so I cant troubleshoot and find the point where it breaks, but I get no result, so I  know it doesnt work

```
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false              # <-- set this according to your requirements
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {  
    $FilePath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    Invoke-Expression C:\PSscript\Action.ps1
}
```

Comment: Why at all use `Invoke-Expression` here?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it depends on the scope where the variable is defined. Global scope variables defined by the parent script are accessible from child scripts but script or local scope variables are not.

---

Note that you don't need Invoke-Expression at all (and [Microsoft advises against using it unnecesarily](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful.aspx)). Just call the child script directly.

There are several ways to access variables defined in the parent script from a child script, but the best is probably to make use of `param()` because you'll be passing variables explicitly:

Parent script:

```
$FilePath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
C:\PSscript\Action.ps1 -FilePath $FilePath # passing $FilePath to child
```

Child script (before any other code):

```
param(
    [String]$FilePath # acquiring $FilePath passed by parent
)
```

However, if you really want to pass variables between scripts implicitly, you can simply use global scope:

```
$global:FilePath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
# Here you go, $global:FilePath is now accessible from anywhere in the session, including
# script blocks, functions and child scripts.
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. I have just begun learning powershell, so most of my code is based on whatever I find on google - hence the invoke-Expression, which I just assumed was the way to incude another program since some other code example used it.